# Do I need to invert the subject and verb in questions?

Tags: word-usage, word-order, auxiliary-verbs

I came across this [post](http://qr.ae/lOV35) and makes me wonder about below 2 sentences:

> How **can I** do this?
>
> How **I can** do this?

Considering subject should come before auxillary verb, please clarify if only 1 from above is correct or both are correct giving different meanings to the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking a question, **How can I do this?** is the correct form.
**How I can do this** can't be used for asking questions. This will be used in declarative form.
 e.g., He wonders how I can do this.

Comment: Can I say "How to do this?"

Comment: Though we use it very often, "How to do this?" is not a complete sentence. To say it correctly you can say, "Can you tell me how to do this?" or "How do I do this?".